# Python - subprocess error

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a button at my window. If I cklick it, I want to start the VLC and stream an URL.

```
def startstream():
    args = ['C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe', 'http://dreambox:8001/1:0:19:7B:B:85:C00000:0:0:0:']
    subprocess.call(args)

# Buttons
button_tnt = Button(fenster, text = "TNT Serie HD", command = startstream)
```

This works as I want.

The following one doesn't work like I want it and I have no idea why not.

```
def startstream(url):
    args = ['C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe', url]
    subprocess.call(args)

# Buttons
button_tnt = Button(fenster, text = "TNT Serie HD", command = startstream('http://dreambox:8001/1:0:19:7B:B:85:C00000:0:0:0:'))
```

With the first code, the window appears and nothing happen. If I click the button, the stream starts, perfect.

Second code: I run the script and the stream starts immediatelly. After I close the VLC I cannot reopen the stream over the button, it has no function.

But I want to use the second code. I have more than one button and so I can only change the argument for each button. With the first code I have to write a new function for every stream.

Please help me :(

Thanks!

Comment: Which GUI kit are you working with? I can spot the issue - `command=startstream(blah)` is calling startstream immediately. You need to still have `command=startstream` but a way of passing the arg to it

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell you. tkinter

Comment: unrelated: use subprocess.Popen instead of subprocess.call to avoid blocking the GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing `startstream` instead of assigning it*. To give it arguments, use the following:

```
button_tnt = Button(fenster, 
                    text="TNT Serie HD",
                    command= lambda: startstream('http://dreambox:8001/1:0:19:7B:B:85:C00000:0:0:0:'))
```

*specifically, you're executing `startstream(..)` and assigning the result of *that* to `command`.
The `lambda` will instead create the function that command will call when clicked.

Comment: Wow. Works amazing. But I have no idea why :D I think I have to do some research here. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem - if you want further reading into why this works, read up on `lambda` (anonymous) functions. Essentially, instead of assigning the return value of `startstream(..)` to `command` (Which we don't want of course), `lambda` _returns the function itself_.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, that when constructing Button, purpose of `command` argument is to define a function to be called, when the button is called.

Your first example does that, it assigns name of a function to call.

In second you do not assign a function, but result of calling the `startstream` call. That is why it starts streaming immediately.

If you really want to assign a function using the `url`, you may do so this way:

```
from functools import partial

# Buttons
button_tnt = Button(fenster, text = "TNT Serie HD", command = partial(startstream, 'http://dreambox:8001/1:0:19:7B:B:85:C00000:0:0:0:'))
```

The `partial` will create a new function, which will call startstream with given parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that in your second example you're not passing arguments to `startstream` on click, you're *calling* startstream *when* you create your button.

```
button_tnt = Button(fenster, 
                    text = "TNT Serie HD", 
                    command = startstream('http://dreambox:8001/1:0:19:7B:B:85:C00000:0:0:0:'))
                                       # ^ Invocation takes place right here.
```

Comment: Interesting information. Thanks so far. Do you have an idea how to solve?